# Does Ubuntu install drivers automatically?

Tags: drivers, software-installation

I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04 from Windows 7.

Will Ubuntu automatically install drivers by downloading them from the internet?

Answer (score 0):

For the majority of your hardware,it will just work out of the box as the drivers are built into the Linux kernel. Should you have something that does not work, feel free to ask a new question. You can test out the hardware compatibility by booting using a live CD live or live USB stick. See the download instructions at http://ubuntu.com.